# Take a value from textarea then paste it in another windows?

Tags: javascript

i want to get a value of textarea then open a new window that contains another textarea and paste the value there using javascript .

i tried that with fail , any hint ?

```
function sharex() {
var post = document.getElementById('msgxvmid').value;
window.open('http://www.google.com' , document.getElementById('vB_Editor_QR_textarea').value = post);
}
```

**EDIT**: i want to do that on the same site with another page (Google link is just an example)

Comment: Why not do this through the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript would probably not be the best way to do this, but if you only want to do this internally, here's a solution:

On your first page, open the window and add a parameter behind the URL with the text you want to paste on the other page, for example

```
window.open('otherpage.html?post=this is the pasted value');
```

On the other page `otherpage.html` in this example you retrieve the parameter's value from the url:

```
var url = new String(decodeURI(window.location));
var post = url.match(/\?post=(.+)/)[1];
```

(In this example the parameter name has to be *post* to get the value, but you can modify the regex to match as many parameters as you want).

Also add a function to change the contents of your `vB_Editor_QR_textarea`

```
function setValues()
{
    document.getElementById('vB_Editor_QR_textarea').value = post;
}
```

And of course call this function when the body loads

```
<body onload="setValues()">
<textarea id="vB_Editor_QR_textarea"></textarea>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!